# How to rename standart django-registration templates' names

Tags: django, django-authentication

I am using django-registration standard urlpatterns, but i want to rename its template name. By default it is "registration/login.html". In source code there is a parameter "template_name" that i want to change:

```
class LoginView(RedirectURLMixin, FormView):
"""
Display the login form and handle the login action.
"""

form_class = AuthenticationForm
authentication_form = None
template_name = "registration/login.html"
redirect_authenticated_user = False
extra_context = None
```

How and where i can do it? (p.s. django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView.template_name = name is not working, or i just write it in incorrect place)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change it in urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
   ...
   path('login/', auth.LoginView.as_view(template_name="new_name_login.html"), ...)
]
```

or you can create your own view (views.py) that is inheriting from the default one:

```
class MyLoginView(LoginView):
    template_name="new_name_login.html"
    ...
```